# export 'useSyncExternalStore' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

When trying to run my project I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/useMediaQuery/useMediaQuery.js 78:16-42

export 'useSyncExternalStore' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: Children, Component, Fragment, Profiler, PureComponent, StrictMode, Suspense, __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED, cloneElement, createContext, createElement, createFactory, createRef, forwardRef, isValidElement, lazy, memo, useCallback, useContext, useDebugValue, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useMemo, useReducer, useRef, useState, version)
```

The problematic file with the error has a function that looks like this:

```
function useMediaQueryNew(query, defaultMatches, matchMedia, ssrMatchMedia) {
  const getDefaultSnapshot = React.useCallback(() => defaultMatches, [defaultMatches]);
  const getServerSnapshot = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (ssrMatchMedia !== null) {
      const {
        matches
      } = ssrMatchMedia(query);
      return () => matches;
    }

    return getDefaultSnapshot;
  }, [getDefaultSnapshot, query, ssrMatchMedia]);
  const [getSnapshot, subscribe] = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (matchMedia === null) {
      return [getDefaultSnapshot, () => () => {}];
    }

    const mediaQueryList = matchMedia(query);
    return [() => mediaQueryList.matches, notify => {
      // TODO: Use `addEventListener` once support for Safari < 14 is dropped
      mediaQueryList.addListener(notify);
      return () => {
        mediaQueryList.removeListener(notify);
      };
    }];
  }, [getDefaultSnapshot, matchMedia, query]);
  const match = React.useSyncExternalStore(subscribe, getSnapshot, getServerSnapshot);
// the problem lies on the upper line of code
  return match;
}
```

I do not know how to solve this problem and have been googling for a while without finding sufficient solutions, any ideas?

Comment: What version of react are you on? `useSyncExternalStore` exists in the beta release for version 18, but is not in earlier versions, such as 17.

Comment: 17.0.2, I think

Comment: Is `useMediaQueryNew` a function you wrote, or something you're importing from a library?

Comment: If you want to use `useMediaQueryNew`, you'll need to upgrade your version of react to the version 18 beta. The other option is to not use this code, which either means rewriting it (if it's part of your codebase), or importing a different version of the library which was written for react 17

Comment: Also, it appears the react team has implemented a shim you could add to allow useSyncExternalStore to be used in older versions of react: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sync-external-store

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved after upgrading to `react v18`

```bash
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
npm install -d @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest
```

Of course, you have to migrate your app.
https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I upgraded `react-scripts` from 4.0.3 to 5.0.0

[Issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29860) was fixed in `@mui/material@^5.2.1`